# Using the result of Solve in subsequent calculations

Tags: programming, syntax

I'd like to know how to use the results of `Solve` in later calculations. Here's what I'm doing now:

- This is my expression

  ```
  g == Solve[g a - b d - f == g c - b e, g]
  ```

  which gives the result `{{g -> (b d - b e + f)/(a - c)}}`
- Next, using the above result, I do

  ```
  Solve[{g == (b d + f - e b)/(a - c), b == 0}, {g, b}]
  ```

  which yields the final result: `{{g -> f/(a - c), b -> 0}}`

I want to do the same calculation without putting the first result into the second calculation "manually". There must be way to tell *Mathematica* that it has to take `g` and insert it into the next calculation by itself.
However, I failed. I tried things like `%` or `/.` but it didn't work.

Comment: just `Solve[{g == (b d + f - e b)/(a - c), b == 0}, {g, b}]` gives your final result

Comment: I know, see above. But my question was how to use the previous result (I need this for longer calculations). As the result to be used is not just g=5, I don't know how to do this. If it was g=5, eg, I could do it using %..

Comment: In this particular example you could do `sol=Solve[g a - b d - f == g c - b e, g]`, `sol /. b -> 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
g1 = Solve[g a - b d - f == g c - b e, g][[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Equal
Solve[{g1, b == 0}, {g, b}]
```

`g1` is the solution of your first equation, made from a `Rule` into an `Equal`. You can even nest the two steps into one:

```
Solve[{Solve[g a - b d - f == g c - b e, g][[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Equal, b == 0}, {g, b}]
```

> Out= {{g -> f/(a - c), b -> 0}}

Answer (score 5):

```
result = Solve[g a - b d - f == g c - b e, g]
Solve[{g==(g/.First@result),b==0},{b,g}]
```

Comment: Yes, that'it, thanks to you both, Peter and celtschk!!

Answer (score 4):

You might use a new function `toEquals` in (inverse) analogy to the built-in `ToRules`:

```
toEquals[x : {{__Rule} ..}] := Or @@ And @@@ (x /. Rule -> Equal)
toEquals[x_] := x
```

This will convert the output of `Solve` into a form that may be used as input.

Then:

```
Solve[g a - b d - f == g c - b e, g]

Solve[toEquals[%] && b == 0, {g, b}]
```

You could potentially use `Fold` to automate this substitution:

```
FoldList[
  Solve[toEquals[#] && #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &,
  True,
  {
   {g a - b d - f == g c - b e, g},
   {b == 0, {g, b}}
  }
] // Rest
```

> ```
> {
>  {{g -> (b d - b e + f)/(a - c)}},
>  {{g -> f/(a - c), b -> 0}}
> }
> ```

That's a lot of code for a simple operation but if you need many layers of substitution it may help.

Answer (score 3):

First it is resonable to do a simplification, adding the second argument to `Simplify` or to `Refine` i.e. an assumption :

```
Simplify[g a - b d - f == g c - b e, b == 0]
```

> ```
> a g == f + c g
> ```

So to make the task in one step  try this :

```
Solve[ Simplify[ g a - b d - f == g c - b e, b == 0], g]
```

> ```
> {{g -> f/(a - c)}}
> ```

or directly solve a system, e.g.

```
Solve[{g a - b d - f == g c - b e, b == 0}, {g, b}]
```