# How to use results of NDsolve[] for further solving of ODEs?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, replacement

I have a system of ODEs with 10 eqns. I can solve the first 5 independently. How can I use those results to solve for the remaining 5?

An easy example would be

$\dot{x}=f(x), \quad 
\dot{y}=g(x,y)$

I can solve for x and now I want to use the interpolating function to solve for y.

Thanks

Comment: Closely related question: [Using the result of Solve in subsequent calculations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6796/245)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is very straightforward - use the solution "interpolating function" as a regular function. Solve a first-order ordinary differential equation, which gives you sort of decaying oscillations:

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
```

Use it inside another equation.  The important thing to remember is that the domain of the *previous* equations should be equal or contain inside the domain of *next* equations.

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{z'[x]== -z[x]^2+First[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol1]], z[0] == 0}, z, {x, 0, 30}]
```

Plot both. It "makes sense". Indeed 1st solution here plays the role of sort of a driving force, so on the graphs below you see synchronization between oscillations.

```
Plot[{Evaluate[y[x] /. sol1], Evaluate[z[x] /. sol2]}, {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now you can do more advanced things, like using also *derivative* of the "Interpolating Function" inside of new equations:

```
sol3 = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
sol4 = NDSolve[{z'[x]== -z[x]+First[y[x]/5 + y'[x] /. sol3], z[0] == 0}, z, {x, 0, 30}];
Plot[{Evaluate[y[x] /. sol3], Evaluate[z[x] /. sol4]}, {x, 0, 30},
      PlotRange -> All, Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that is what I tried and it didn't work. But after a close look upon my eqns, I noticed that I accidentally deleted some of my eqns. But thanks anyway. At least I knew it had to be something different.

Comment: @Lisa I am glad you figured it out. Welcome to the community! You may want to take a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 6):

From the question it seems that you're working with `NDSolve` (not `DSolve`) because you're asking about `InterpolatingFunction`.

As long as you solve all equations for the same domain of the independent variable (let's call it `t`), it should be possible to use the the results as in this example:

```
Clear[x, y, t]

xFn = 
 First[x /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}]]

NDSolve[{y'[t] == 2 xFn[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 1}]


Plot[Evaluate[First[y /. %]][t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: ndsolve result]

The main thing is to convert the rule specifying the first solution into a function named `xFn`.

Answer (score 2):

An example:

```
s = DSolve[Dt[x[t], t] == x[t]^2, x[t], t]
DSolve[Dt[y[t], t] == (x[t] y[t])^2 /. s[[1]], y[t], t]
(*
{{y[t] -> (-t - C[1])/(-1 + t C[2] + C[1] C[2])}}
*)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the `interpolating function` part of your question. This answer is for symbolically solved diff eqs. I'll leave it here anyway so it may help others-