# Function output from DSolve

Tags: functions, differential-equations

I want to get a function as output form DSolve. 
For Example :

```
sol = DSolve[{Q''[t] + 40 Q'[t] + 625 Q[t] == 100*Cos[10*t], Q[0] == 0, Q'[0] == 0}, Q[t], t]
```

I want to use Q[t] as a function to use in an another equation.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6664/121

Comment: Almost the same question: [How to use results of NDsolve for further solving of ODEs?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8610/245)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not too hard:

```
dsaad[t_] = Q[t] /. First @ DSolve[{Q''[t] + 40 Q'[t] + 625 Q[t] == 100*Cos[10*t],
                                   Q[0] == 0, Q'[0] == 0}, Q, t]
```

Notes:

1. I instructed `DSolve[]` to return the pure function `Q` (through the second argument) instead of the function itself to ease the replacement.
2. I used `Set[]` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed[]` (`:=`), so that the replacement is done at once before the definition takes place.

---

Another possibility is to use `DifferentialRoot[]` instead:

```
dsaad[x_] := DifferentialRoot[Function[{Q, t},
               {Q''[t] + 40 Q'[t] + 625 Q[t] == 100*Cos[10*t], Q[0] == 0, Q'[0] == 0}]][x]
```

Comment: I understand all of it but I didn't get the "First".

What does it?

Comment: @DSaad The First is meant to extract the solution as it is returned by Mathematica as a List of List.