# How to find the Mean of results given as a list of Rules?

Tags: rule

How can we find the mean of the following type of data?

```
{{β -> 0.516819}, {β -> 0.499907}, 
 {β -> 0.494064}, {β -> 0.472742}, 
 {β -> 0.537485}, {β -> 0.478291}, 
 {β -> 0.523855}, {β -> 0.483624}, 
 {β -> 0.50126},  {β -> 0.527267}}
```

Which command could be used to find the mean of this data?

Comment: Welcome to SE! It will help those might answer if you would please post code that is syntactically correct and properly formatted. See [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: This should be helpful: [Using the result of Solve in subsequent calculations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6796/using-the-result-of-solve-in-subsequent-calculations), together with [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mean.html).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Sorry, it was involuntary. Please rollback my edit to yours if think it better. (or merge both!)

Answer (score 5):

```
Mean[beta /. {{beta -> 0.516819}, {beta -> 0.499907}, {beta -> 
     0.494064}, {beta -> 0.472742}, {beta -> 0.537485}, {beta -> 
     0.478291}, {beta -> 0.523855}, {beta -> 0.483624}, {beta -> 
     0.50126}, {beta -> 0.527267}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

[Beta] is bad syntax, so i replaced all by beta

```
Mean[{{beta->0.516819},{beta->0.499907},{beta->0.494064},{beta->0.472742},
{beta->0.537485},{beta->0.478291},{beta->0.523855},{beta->0.483624},{beta->0.50126},
{beta->0.527267}}[[All,1,2]]]
```

If you want the variance, try opening the documentation and search for it

Answer (score 3):

*Considering the votes, I think Timings are in order.*

*Double semicolons are intentional, they prevent extra memory use when $HistoryLength > 1*

**Timing comparison between other answers**

```
nn = 1*^6;
rands = RandomReal[1, nn]; ;
data = {b -> #} & /@ rands; ;

Mean@data[[All, 1, 2]] // Timing
Mean@(b /. data) // Timing
```

Outputs

```
{0.069164, 0.500199}
{0.983088, 0.500199}
```

**Perhaps also noteworthy**

```
<<Developer`
data[[All, 1, 2]] // PackedArrayQ
(b /. data) // PackedArrayQ
```

Outputs

```
False
False
```